# how to upload client files directly to minio?

Tags: node.js, express, upload, client, minio

is there any way to uplaod files directly from client to minio s3? im working nodejs with express and want to have something to do this without proxing hosting to upload files like using multer. in the below example i used cloudinary and multer with proxing hosting to recive the payload from the client and then the hosting will do the uploading:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const cloudinary = require('../../configs/uploader.configs')
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary')

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary,
    params: {
        folder: 'musics',
        resource_type: 'video'
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage })

module.exports = upload.single('music')
```

Comment: multer is known to have memory issues . you could follow the thread https://github.com/minio/minio-js/issues/1045